# how to use dynamic variable in purrr map within dplyr

Tags: r, purrr

I have the following data which looks like that:

```
tibble(
  name = paste0("segment",1),
  data = list(tibble(segment1 = 1:5, check = 99))
)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  name     data            
  <chr>    <list>          
1 segment1 <tibble [5 x 2]>
```

I want to map over the nested data and want to use a variable (name) in dplyr. If in column name **segment1** is 2 than 66 otherwise use values from column **segment1**

```
tibble(
  name = paste0("segment",1),
  data = list(tibble(segment1 = 1:5, check = 99))
) %>% 
  
  mutate(testing = map2(.x = name, .y = data, 
                        ~ .y %>% 
                            mutate(testing = ifelse((!!.x) == 2, 66, (!!.x)))))
```

The unnested testing tibble should look like:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  segment1 check testing
     <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
1        1    99       1
2        2    99      66
3        3    99       3
4        4    99       4
5        5    99       5
```

But I always get the error that .x couldn't be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.x` is already used for `map2`, it is better to use anonymous function to be clear which variable is referred to what.

To use string variables as column name `.data` pronoun should work but I am surprised it doesn't work here (or I am not using it correctly). An alternative is to use `get`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

tibble(
  name = paste0("segment",1),
  data = list(tibble(segment1 = 1:5, check = 99))
) %>%
  mutate(testing = map2(name, data, function(p, q) {
    q %>% mutate(testing = ifelse(get(p) == 2, 66, get(p)))
  })) 

#   name     data             testing         
#  <chr>    <list>           <list>          
#1 segment1 <tibble [5 × 2]> <tibble [5 × 3]>
```

where data in `testing` column is

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  segment1 check testing
#     <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1        1    99       1
#2        2    99      66
#3        3    99       3
#4        4    99       4
#5        5    99       5
```