# dplyr mutate and purrr map: use data masking to select columns for map

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, mutate

In a dplyr mutate context, I would like to select the column a function is applied to by purrr:map using the value of another column.

Let's take a test data frame

```r
test <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4), selector = c("a","b"))
```

I want to apply following function

```
calc <- function(col)
{res <- col ^ 2
return(res)
}
```

I am trying something like this:

```
test_2 <- test %>% mutate(quad = map(.data[[selector]], ~ calc(.x)))
```

My expected result would be:

```r
  a b selector quad
1 1 3        a    1
2 2 4        b   16
```

but I get

```
Error in local_error_context(dots = dots, .index = i, mask = mask) : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

I know `.data[[var]]` is supposed to be used only in special context of function programming, but also if I wrap this in functions or similar I cannot get it done. Trying to use tidy-selection gives the error that selecting helpers can only be used in special dplyr verbs, not functions like purrr:map.

[how to use dynamic variable in purrr map within dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68953653/how-to-use-dynamic-variable-in-purrr-map-within-dplyr)
hinted me to use `get()` and anonymous functions, but this also did not work in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```r
test %>% 
  mutate(quad = map(seq_along(selector), ~ calc(test[[selector[.x]]])[.x]))

#   a b selector quad
# 1 1 3        a    1
# 2 2 4        b   16
```

Instead of `.data`, you can also `cur_data` (which accounts for grouping):

```r
test %>% 
  mutate(quad = map(seq(selector), ~ calc(cur_data()[[selector[.x]]])[.x]))
```

---

Or, with `diag`:

```r
test %>% 
  mutate(quad = diag(as.matrix(calc(cur_data()[selector]))))

#  a b selector quad
#1 1 3        a    1
#2 2 4        b   16
```

Comment: I didn't know about seq_along - very interesting!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't think about simply subsetting the selector in the function, the seq_along is great for this!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rowwise()` and `get()` the selector variable:

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(quad = calc(get(selector))) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 × 4
      a     b selector  quad
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1     1     3 a            1
2     2     4 b           16
```

Or if the selector repeats, `group_by()` will be more efficient:

```
test <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,5), b = c(3,4,6), selector = c("a","b","a"))

test %>%
  group_by(selector) %>%
  mutate(quad = calc(get(selector[1]))) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 × 4
      a     b selector  quad
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1     1     3 a            1
2     2     4 b           16
3     5     6 a           25
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also change the function to return a single number and use `purrr`:

```
calc <- function(col, id) {test[[col]][[id]]^2}

test %>% 
    mutate(
        quad = purrr::map2_dbl(selector, row_number(), calc)
    )
  a b selector quad
1 1 3        a    1
2 2 4        b   16
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
test$quad <- calc(test[,test$selector][cbind(seq_len(nrow(test)), test$selector)])
```

(R version 3.5.3 where strings are converted to factors in `data.frame`)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you asked for but an alternative might be to restructure the data so that the calculation is easier:

```
test %>% 
   pivot_longer(
       cols = c(a, b)
   ) %>% 
   filter(name == selector) %>% 
   mutate(quad = value**2)

# A tibble: 2 × 4
  selector name  value  quad
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        a         1     1
2 b        b         4    16
```

You can join the results back onto the original data using an id column.